# No rule to make target 'install' [cmake]

Tags: c++, linux, tensorflow, cmake, yocto

While compiling the [minimal.cpp](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal) example of TensorFlow Lite with cmake on Yocto platform, we are having error as follows:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| NOTE: make -j 4 DESTDIR=/home/student/fsl-release-bsp/build-analytics-tflite/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/minimal/1.0-r0/image install
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/student/fsl-release-bsp/build-analytics-tflite/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.2654)
ERROR: Task (/home/student/fsl-release-bsp/sources/meta-analytics-tflite/recipes-hello/patch/minimal.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1787 tasks of which 1786 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

On the install line of our *CMakeLists.txt* file the idea is not clear in our mind about "TARGETS". If you brighten up our mind it would be perfect.

- The CMakeLists.txt file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(patch)

add_executable(minimal minimal.cc)

target_include_directories(minimal PUBLIC /home/student/fsl-release-bsp/build-analytics-tflite/tmp/sysroots/analytics/usr/include/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include)

target_link_libraries(minimal tensorflow-lite pthread ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

install(TARGETS patch DESTINATION git)
```

Your guidance and clarifications are important for us.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `install(TARGETS)` implies installing **targets**, but there is no `patch` target defined in your `CMakeLists.txt`. You only define `minimal` target (via `add_executable`).

Comment: You are right that is our fault, 'patch' was the name of github repo that the .cpp and .txt files stored and cloned. But also when we try as `install(TARGETS minimal DESTINATION git)` , still we are having the same error as above.

Comment: [crosspost on discourse.cmake.org](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/no-rule-to-make-target-install/3170)